# Silent Installation of MSI file while Main MSI file Installing

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I created a windows forms project, and created a MSI file to install that windows application into client machine.

While Installing that MSI file, I check If the user using windows xp then I download a MSI file from internet and installing it in programatically using C#.

Since both files are MSI, so I am getting the following error.

Image link for the Error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A6WW.png

I am using Installer class in C#. Installing that file by overriding the Commit function.

How can I successfully Install that ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? I couldnt see your erro image.

Answer (score 1):

Put the second installation in the prerequisites of the first. If second is unavailable then first it will install that after that your main program.